# Existe-t-il un pangramme phonémique parfait en français ?

Tags: phonétique

Un « pangramme phonémique » est une phrase qui contient chaque phonème de la langue; il est « parfait » si chacun n’apparaît qu'une fois comme, par exemple, en anglais, cette phrase prononcée avec certains accents d'Amérique du Nord :

> Shaw, those twelve beige hooks are joined if I patch a young, gooey mouth.
>
> /ʃɒ ðoʊz twɛlv beɪʒ hʊks ɑr ʤɔɪnd ɪf aɪ pæʧ ə jʌŋ, guːiː maʊθ/

Est-ce qu'on peut construire quelque chose de similaire en français ? J'ai commencé par éliminer des phonèmes moins communs :

> peignons leurs huit âmes
>
> pɛɲɔ̃ lœʁ ɥit ɑm

mais après avoir essayé deux heures, mon vocabulaire limité ne m'a pas permis de réussir. Est-ce qu'une telle phrase existe et si elle n'existe pas, un locuteur natif pourrait-il la créer ?

Pour les besoins de cette question, supposons que seuls soient retenus les phonèmes du français définis en Alphabet Phonétique International. Je sais que la différence entre certains d'entre eux disparait; n'en tenons pas compte.

> Consonnes: m p b f v n t d s z l ʃ ʒ ɲ j ɥ k g w ʁ
>
> Voyelles : a e i o u ɑ ɛ y ɔ ø œ ə ɑ̃ ɛ̃ ɔ̃ œ̃

Comment: Ah, @jlliagre. Je suis toujours gêné par les erreurs que vous devez corriger.

Comment: Pas de problème. Quelle est votre/ta langue maternelle ?

Comment: @jlliagre C'est anglais. En fait, si je peux me vanter, j'ai créé le pangramme phonémique en anglais que vous voyez dans cette question. On peut ailleurs le trouver en ligne parce que je l'ai ajouté à Wikipedia.

Comment: Le problème c'est qu'il soit parfait...  « une fois » c'est dur. Je cale au bout de deux heures ! (Au fait en français on dirait plutôt  « sans vouloir me vanter » (If I may boast).

Comment: @EMBLEM ne voyez pas les corrections faites par jlliagre comme quelque chose de négatif, au contraire. On vous corrige pour que vous soyez conscient(e) de vos erreurs, et que vous puissiez progresser :)

Comment: Je m'y essayerai ! En attendant, ne connaissant pas l'alphabet phonétique, j'ai trouvé cette page wikipédia qui recense les différents phonèmes francophones en donnant leurs différentes écritures possibles avec des exemples d'utilisation : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_graphies_des_phon%C3%A8mes_du_fran%C3%A7ais
Un algorithme et un dictionnaire seraient-ils capables de venir à bout de ce problème ?

Comment: @Kii Oui, s'ils existent.

Answer (score 3):

Bonjour,

Je me suis inscrit sur cette communauté hier et tombe par hasard sur cette vieille question. 
Je suis abonné depuis des années à une mailing liste tournant autour de l'*OuLiPo* (OUvroir de LIttérature POtentielle - cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oulipo) et donc de la littérature à contraintes.

Cette contrainte de pangramme phonémique, comme vous l'appelez, a été adressée en 2002 et appelée hétéropanphonème.
Vous trouverez ici dans les archives d'un des membres quelques essais:
http://www.gef.free.fr/oulipo10.html#date080202

(j'en reprends un ici à titre d'exemple:

> Un gosse puant, jeune, a deux gnons. Coutume ? Ouais, chose
>   invérifiable !

)

Et du même membre, GeF, bien plus impressionnant, un sonnet octosyllabique entièrement constitué de telles pangrammes phonémiques.
Détails: http://www.gef.free.fr/oulipo10.html#pansonneme

> *Lettre d'un vieux gourmand*
>
> *à une gente damoiselle,*
>
> *suivie de sa réponse
>
> J'étais un vigneron pas bien,
>
> homme aux choix luxueux, doux gants neufs.
>
> Présentons-nous chu comme un veuf,
>
> agneau bleu : je suis gai doyen.
>
> Chanceux, j'avais plus d'un moyen :
>
> te cuire aux oignons gnou et boeuf.
>
> Vois : du rhum luit. Je goûte un oeuf
>
> -seize oeufs !- et champagne ô combien...
>
> Viens chez moi, jeunesse, aux campagnes :
>
> un loup on fut, gobeuse d'huîtres !
>
> J'eus un vin chinois, ô compagne.
>
> -- Mais ce gluant bouffeur est odieux !
>
> Jeune, un cochon suant vos épîtres
>
> fait bagne moins goulu. Adieu !

Answer (score 0):

Un bon vin blanc! /œ̃bɔ̃vɛ̃blɑ̃/

Réduction de pangramme phonémique aux voyelles nasales.  Servir frais!